# Symfony4 does not find user according to remember me cookie

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, symfony4, remember-me

I have configured symfony 4 to set a remember me cookie when the users checks a checkbox. This works as it should. But when I restart the Browser and return to the Website the website deletes the cookie. The symfony log looks like this:

```
[Application] Oct 21 14:14:12 |DEBUG  | SECURI Remember-me cookie detected. 
[Application] Oct 21 14:14:12 |INFO   | SECURI User for remember-me cookie not found. 
[Application] Oct 21 14:14:12 |DEBUG  | DOCTRI SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.email AS email_2, t0.roles AS roles_3, t0.password AS password_4, t0.is_verified AS is_verified_5, t0.pending_surfpoints AS pending_surfpoints_6, t0.surfpoints_total AS surfpoints_total_7, t0.balance AS balance_8, t0.username AS username_9, t0.ref_earning AS ref_earning_10, t0.ref_id AS ref_id_11 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.email = ? LIMIT 1 0="myUsername"
[Application] Oct 21 14:14:12 |DEBUG  | SECURI Clearing remember-me cookie. name="REMEMBERME"
```

I configured the User login to work with an email and a username (my changes are mentioned below). I think now the problem is, that the remember me cookie is searching for the username in the username section of my database.

I changed the getUser function in the UserAuthentificatorAuthenticator.php to look for an email, and if that fails for the username:

```
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);


        if (!$user) {
            //Email could not be found - try username
            $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $credentials['email']]);
            if (!$user){
                // fail authentication with a custom error
                throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email/Username konnten nicht gefunden werden.');
            }

        }
        if (!$user->isVerified()){
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Der Account wurde noch nicht aktiviert.');

        }

        return $user;
    }
```

Where can I now adapt the cookie authentificator to make it work?

Edit:
My security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\UserAuthentificatorAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                target: app_default_start
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /
```

Comment: what config do you have in securtiy.yaml?
be sure you'r config must be correct you can read more about it [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/security/remember_me.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in `EntityUserProvider` you are using now looks up the `User` object according to the property specified in the configuration. The remember me feature uses the `Provider` to look up the user, and as your user can log in using either `email` or `username`, when looking up by `email` only, the user is not found with the default one.  You should move the lookup logic out of the `Authenticator` and into a [`UserProvider`](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/security/user_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user).

Add the following function to your `UserRepository` and make it `implement UserLoaderInterface`:

```
public function loadUserByUsername($identifier)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    return $qb->where('u.username = :identifier')
        ->orWhere('u.email = :identifier')
        ->setParameter('identifier', $identifier)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

In `security.yaml`, remove `property`:

```
app_user_provider:
    entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
```

Change your authenticator:

```
$token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
    throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
}

$user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials['email']);

if (!$user) {
    throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email/Username konnten nicht gefunden werden.');
}

if (!$user->isVerified()){
    throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Der Account wurde noch nicht aktiviert.');
}

return $user;
```